# Cross-browser CSS issues in custom social sharing widget

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I'm having a horrible time trying to get a custom social sharing widget to work in my Wordpress template.

What works on CSSDeck and Dabblet, and also live in Firefox, doesn't work in Chrome or Safari, and right now I'm at a loss to understand what's going wrong, or how to fix it.

To see the code in action, see the links below:

CSSDeck: http://cssdeck.com/labs/zjc2m9rl
My live site: http://tinyurl.com/qaddxwm

Can anyone give any pointers as to why this is not working in Chrome/Safari?

There are three problems: 1) The social sharing icons should be hidden on load, but they aren't (works in Firefox fairly well). 2) You should be able to hide or show the social sharing icons by clicking the main Share icon (works in Firefox, doesn't work at all on Chrome/Safari). 3) Hover over the social icons should turn them white (works in Firefox, but some even disappear in Chrome/Safari).

(p.s., If some of my classes are weirdly named, it's because the classes in the original Codepen widget upon which this widget is based conflicted with existing classes in my theme.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just saw it in Chrome and works perfect for me, it starts with icons hidden, shows/hides when click and change color when :hover

**EDIT:**

Found the problem in your web, just add the -webkit- prefix to all the transform:; values in .postsocialshare

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Are you talking about the live site, or the CSSDeck snippet? I've cleared all browser data in Chrome and still it is the same. Doesn't hide on opening; doesn't hover properly; can't click open and shut. The CSSDeck works for me, of course. This is the point. The live site with the same code doesn't.

Comment: Just found the problem, checkout above ;)

Comment: Fabulous! That fixed it in all browsers. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Just for anyone who finds this who has a similar issue, you need to duplicate the transform values, leaving it plain for Firefox, and adding -webkit- for other browsers.